# Nested exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, xml, spring

Скачал библиотеки Spring через Gradle и просто закинул в Eclipse.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cs =
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:C:/Users/Владислав/temp/HHH/src/resources/xml-beans.xml");
System.out.println(cs.getBeanDefinitionCount());
```

Ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [C:/Users/Владислав/temp/HHH/src/resources/xml-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [C:/Users/Владислав/temp/HHH/src/resources/xml-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)

P.s. Пути по-всякому указывал, пробовал записывать путь в calasspath. Так что дело не в правильности указания пути.

Comment: "class path resource [C:/Users/Владислав/temp/HHH/src/resources/xml-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist" - перевод требуется?

Comment: Если бы мне нужен был перевод, я бы обратился к гуглу, но тут реально не работает из-за каких-то особенностей класса. Потому что как бы я не записывал путь, ничего не меняется

Comment: В вопросе об этом ни слова

Comment: Конечно из-за особенностей класса.  Особенность в том, что `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` грузит xml из `CLASSPATH`, а вы передаете абсолютный путь в файловой системе.

Comment: Я же сказал, пробовал и не абсолютный путь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать FileSystemXmlApplicationContext (для загрузки xml )

Comment: Большое спасибо, то, что было нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь открыть файл с абсолютным путем через classpath. Делать этого не нужно, т.к. это немного ортогональные понятия: classpath подразумевает расположение файла внутри артефакта, как бы он не был упакован, а абсолютный путь - это путь на текущей машине, не имеющий ничего общего наборот с артефактом. Если мы берем классический джарник - который представляет из себя просто zip-архив артефакта - то classpath будет соответствовать корню архива, т.е. отсчет путей будет вестись изнутри архивированной папки. Естественно, внутри артефакта не существует пути `C:/...`, поэтому ничего и не открывается. Кроме того, `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` вероятнее всего сам по себе подразумевает префикс `classpath:`, который указывать не надо. Скорее всего, вам будет достаточно указать `xml-beans.xml`.

Comment: Я просто не знал уже, что делать. По всякому пробовал, и в class path добавлял, и писал абсолютный/неабсолютный пути, и добавлял слово classpath и удалял. Ничего не помогает.

Comment: @Vladius001 залезьте руками в джарник/варник, и убедитесь, что файл лежит на месте. ЕМНИП в мавене может быть ситуация, когда плагин ресурсов не отрабатывает, и тогда все добро в resources в артефакте не оказывается.

Comment: Нету Джарника, я не использовал ни мавен, ни градл. Проект в эклипс.

Comment: Как он запускается? Как просто скомпилированные `.class`-файлы?

Comment: Понятия не имею, работает, как и другие IDE.

Comment: Я не про IDE, я про проект.

Comment: Я не знаю, как он запускается, видимо, элклипс его компилирует и запускает.